# Books about famous experiments in biology - 'methods of investigation'

Tags: book-recommendation, experimental-design, literature, history

I'll explain briefly what I need (hoping to find something) :

I wanted to know if someone knew about a book that in a way or another talked about the greatest experiments in biology (Griffith, Avery-MacLeod-MacCarty, Hershey-Chase) or methods normally used to study  certain phenomena  for example, and explaining or talking about the paradigm used in biology research in such cases.

I know it might sound too vague, but I will have a kind of 'exam' essay, in which in addition to the biologic phenomena asked in terms of "notions" one will also have to suggest a 'method of investigation' to study it.

And my main problem is that in school just the theory is normally taught and not the practical approach to such topics, so I really lack knowledge in this.

So what I'm asking is whether there is a certain book or even a suggested approach that I might start using that might help me in learning what I explained above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Honestly, someone needs to write this book.

Comment: Microbe hunters is an excellent book which will fulfill your requirements. You will get an insight into the working of some of the greatest minds....

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not stricly about biology, *A short history of nearly everything* by Bill Bryson, especially chapter 5, is a good start to look for historical experiments.

Answer (score 4):

[The Eighth Day of Creation](http://www.cshlpress.com/default.tpl?cart=146068124146944481&fromlink=T&linkaction=full&linksortby=oop_title&--eqSKUdatarq=294) by Horace Freeland Judson is quite good, in the genre you're looking for. Also, [Science as a way of Knowing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674794826) may fit the bill.